# Unable to RDP to EC2 Spot instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made a spot request on AWS and it has been fulfilled. It is green and says that the status checks are all good to go. However, when I connect to the server via RDP, it just times out.

- **AMI:** Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base-2017.04.12 (ami-9b29b9fb)
- **Instance Type:** p2.xlarge
- **Security Group:** default

All the tests have gone through but I still cannot seem to connect via RDP. Not sure why it is not working as I set up a Windows server earlier and everything was working as expected.

I cannot see any charges either for the spot instances.

Edit: The problem was with the User Groups, needed to add RDP and my internet address to things to get it all working!

Comment: Please add security group of the instance.

Comment: @naveenkerati added

Comment: Please read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html.

Comment: The fact that it is a Spot Instance will have no impact on your ability to login. Take a look at your functionality Windows instance an compare every aspect to discover what is different -- Security Group, Subnet, etc as listed by @ChrisWhite

Answer (score 1):

The usual troubleshooting methods apply here:

1. Make sure the instance has a public IP (Elastic IP or auto-assigned)
2. Make sure the instance is in a public subnet (Has a route to an internet gateway)
3. Make sure your instance's security group allows RDP
4. Make sure your NACL (Network Access Control List) allows inbound and outbound traffic for it
5. You may have been outbid and the instance is in the termination phase when you're trying to connect
6. Check any UserData set which may have put the RDP service in an invalid state

Comment: Thanks ill check through all of these and get back to you.

Comment: 1. Has IP Public address
2. Not sure how to check this but it has a subnet ID
3. Ive checked my instace secutiry group, and doesnt give me the option to allow or not allow RDP, but all ports are enabled, in the outbound rules my IP address is setup
4. I think this is setup correctly? Is it in the security group?
5. Ive not been outbid the instance ins green and sais running
6. Ive not put in any custom user data...

Still not working though, i guess ill have to try again after lunch

Comment: @YasminFrench It sounds like you're just using the default settings for everything. Recommendations: 1. Setup a VPC. There's a wizard that does most of the grunt work for you as described in this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/ExerciseOverview.html). Understanding VPC networking is crucial in identifying networking issues. Launch into that VPC. 2. Setup a security group for your [windows instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#DefaultSecurityGroup). Having all ports open is against AWS best practices.

Comment: I know its a bad practice, but right now im simply attempting to connect to them! Do you have any idea as well why im not seeing any problems with payments?

Comment: @YasminFrench I can't comment on billing issues. You need to contact AWS support through the support center to get help with that. My advice in understanding the VPC concepts still holds though. Setting up your own VPC and booting instances in it gives you a better understanding of your environment so you can debug what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old question. However I faced this issue so though to answer, may be helpful for those who come here via Google. The reason for this in my case was:

**1. Security group:** I already had reserved instance and also had set appropriate inbound rule for RDP port (3389) and I was under impression new spot instance I launched will use same security group. But it did not. So I assigned manually this security group to the instance and then onwards I was able to connect it using RDP

**2. Public IP address:** There was no public IP address so I reserved once (out of pool) and assigned it to the new spot instance.